# Retrieving bmp from CFBundle

Tags: c++, bundle, sdl, resourcebundle

I have a SDL application I am making in xcode.

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //The images
    SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
    SDL_Window* screen = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *sdlRenderer = NULL;

    //Set up screen
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("My Game Window",
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                          640, 480,
                          SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    //Create Renderer
    sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);

    //Load image
    hello = SDL_LoadBMP( "hello.bmp" );

    //Create texture from the surface
    SDL_Texture* hello_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(sdlRenderer, hello);

    //copy texture to the renderer's buffer.
    SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, hello_texture, NULL, NULL);

    //Update Screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);

    //Pause
    SDL_Delay( 5000 );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

So everything works good but no image shows up. After debugging I found that load_bmp returns null. So I tried to figure out what the correct file path should be through this:

```
 CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(mainBundle);
    CFStringRef str = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath( resourcesURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle );
    resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(
                                      mainBundle,
                                      CFSTR("hello.bmp"),
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL
                                      );
```

but that is also not giving me anything so it seems like maybe hello.bmp isn't correctly being copied to the bundle? Has anyone else run into this and no what needs to be done?